# Present dictionary in several NSTableviews

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nsdictionary

I'm a beginner to cocoa and I've been trying to make a simple app for Mac using swift programming language, but I'm stuck and can't find a solution.

I want to present a data from dictionary in two or more tableViews, where the first table will show key, and the second table will show value.

For example, I have a dictionary

```
var worldDict:NSDictionary = ["Africa":["Egypt", "Togo"],"Europe": ["Austria", "Spain"]]
```

I can present all continents in the first table, but I can't find out how to make second table to display countries from continent I choose in the first table.

My ViewController is a DataSource and Delegate for both tables.

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource {
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    if tableView == continentTable {
    return self.worldDict.valueForKey("Continent")!.count
    } else if tableView == countryTable {
        return self.worldDict.valueForKey("Continent")!.allKeys.count
    }
    return 0
} 
 func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    var cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
    if tableView == self.continentTable {
    let continent: AnyObject? = wordlDict.valueForKey("Continent")
        var keys = continent!.allKeys        
    cell.textField?.stringValue = keys[row] as! String
    } else if tableView == self.countryTable {
        var countriesOfContinent: AnyObject? = worldDict.valueForKey("Continent")?.valueForKey("Africa")!
        cell.textField?.stringValue = countriesOfContinent?.allKeys[row] as! String
    }
        return cell
}
```

}

Here I present data from dictionary in tables, but separately, and can't figure out how to make them work together.

Also I know how to get the number of row that has been selected

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {

func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let continentSelected = rowSelected()
}}
func rowSelected() -> Int? {
    let selectedRow = self.continentTable.selectedRow
    if selectedRow >= 0 && selectedRow < self.worldDict.valueForKey("Continent")!.count {
        return selectedRow
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Why don't you share what you've done to get the first table view working and what you tried to get the second table view working? Also, describe exactly have the second table view is failing to work as you want.

Comment: @KenThomases I've added excerpts of code.

Comment: What is the connection between `var countries` and `worldfDict`?

Comment: var countries is an example of a dictionary i use, they are not connected. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're relying on the ordering of the keys returned by `allKeys()` to be reliable, which it's not. You need to keep a separate array of continents. It can basically be a copy of whatever `allKeys()` returned on one occasion, but you should not keep calling `allKeys()` each time.

In `numberOfRowsInTableView()`, for the countries table, you want to return the number of countries in the selected continent:

```
} else if tableView == countryTable {
    if let selectedContinentRow = rowSelected() {
        let selectedContinent = continentsArray[selectedContinentRow]
        return self.worldDict[selectedContinent].count
    }
    return 0
}
```

For `tableView(_:viewForTableColumn:row:)`, you want to return an element from the selected continent's array of countries:

```
} else if tableView == self.countryTable {
    if let selectedContinentRow = rowSelected() {
        let selectedContinent = continentsArray[selectedContinentRow]
        return self.worldDict[selectedContinent][row]
    }
}
```

Also, whenever the selected continent changes, you need to tell the countries table to reload its data:

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    // ... whatever else ...
    let tableView = notification.object as! NSTableView
    if tableView == continentTable {
        countryTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```